# Tastypie - redirect user to new url

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a resource where, if the user's authenticated it returns a json, else it redirects the user to a different url.

Does anyone know if I can redirect like that in Tastypie?

Or do I need to implement some sort of middleware?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

Start with [this](http://sysadminpy.com/programming/2011/11/14/ajax-and-tastypie---check-if-a-user-has-authenticated/) then, return a redirect response if the super doesn't return True

```
resp = super(...)
if resp != True:
   resp = self.createresponse(HttpRedirect(SOME_URL))
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you intend here. I think you should explain and at the very least provide some more context for your code.